# Uppdate an entity in table storage

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I have a script to update the entities in table storage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#updating-entities):

```
[string]$filter = `
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition("Period",`
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,6)
    
    $users = Get-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -customFilter $filter
    
    foreach ($user in $users)
    {
        $user.Period = 24
        $user | Update-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable
    }
```

This doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and successfully updated the period in the entities:**

I followed this [**MS-DOCS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#add-table-entities) to add the four table entities to table storage in my environment.

**Code:**

```
$storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx

$cloudTable = $storageTable.CloudTable

$partitionKey1 = "partition1"
$partitionKey2 = "partition2"

# add four rows 
Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("CA") -property @{"Period"= "2";"userid"=1}

Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey2 `
    -rowKey ("NM") -property @{"Period"="7";"userid"=2}

Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("WA") -property @{"Period"="13";"userid"=3}

Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey2 `
    -rowKey ("TX") -property @{"Period"="15";"userid"=4}

Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable | ft 

Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -partitionKey $partitionKey1 | ft
```

**Output:**

[image]

**To update entity:**

```
# Create a filter and get the entity to be updated.
[string]$filter = `
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition("Period",`
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,"7")
$user = Get-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -customFilter $filter

$user.Period ="24"

# To commit the change, pipe the updated record into the update cmdlet.
$user | Update-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable

# To see the new record, query the table.
Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable `
    -customFilter "(Period eq '24')"
```

The above command executed successfully and updated **`Period 7 to 24`**.

**Console:**

[image]